# Struts2 iterator tag null object does not throw exception

Tags: struts2

I am in a process of migrating struts 1 to struts 2.X

Have attribute set in request scope and I am accesing in my jsp as below in struts 1. when bean is not in scope i get ".servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean cat in any scope"

```
<div class="titlePageCatalog"><bean:write name="desccategory" property="name" /></div>
```

And in struts 2 i modified to

```
<s:iterator value="#request.cat">
<div class="titlePageCatalog">  <s:property value = "name"/></div>
</s:iterator>
```

But in struts 2 i am not getting any exception. Basically i need that exception to be thrown when cat is not set.

Can anyone please suggest how to get an jspexception when its not set

Comment: you can SetError Message from Business Logic...Like if cat==null or cat.isEmpty(if it is list) then setError("Cat not setted");,then Access in jsp using <s:property value="Error"/> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw exception in your java code where your are processing request as, [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) is part of your view where you should only focus on delivering result / response. Exceptions throwing / handling should be part of your Controller / Business layers job. This must be one of the reasons  that `s:iterator` does not throw any **uncalled** for [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp)[exceptions](/questions/tagged/exceptions) in [struts2](/questions/tagged/struts2) releases.

If attribute `cat` is mandatory for your view you should check it before you return result from your struts action. If you expect `cat` to be null and show appropriate message to user then may be you should use something like this

```
<s:if test="%{cat.isEmpty()}">
   Some error occurred in this part of page but rest of result is being displayed
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:iterator value="cat">
        Your display code.
    </s:iterator> 
</s:else>
```